# How do you check if a list has an entry with certain values?

Tags: python

It's a bit hard to explain my problem, but I'll do my best.

I have a .csv file with around 38k entries, and all entries are the same format. The format is: 
Name1, party1, name2, party2, date, URL

Now I need to search through this .csv file and check for each entry if the turned names and parties exists.

So for example, I have the following entry:

```
S. Faber, CDA, J.A. v. Kemenade, PvdA, 1980.06.24, http://polidocs.nl/XML/MOT/1970028.xml
```

Where

```
name1 = S. Faber, 
party1 = CDA, 
name2 = J.A. v. Kemenade, 
party2 = PvdA, 
date = 1980.06.24, 
URL = http://polidocs.nl/XML/MOT/1970028.xml
```

Now I need to check if there is an entry with these exact values:
J.A. v. Kememande, PvdA, S. Faber, CDA, date, URL <- where date and URL dont matter

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have examples of code that you've tried?

Comment: have you tried the `in` operator?

Comment: Not anymore, I tried some weird stuff but all of it ended up in errors. I'm pretty much totally lost.

Comment: I've tried the in operator, but how do you check if only a part of the entry is in the list?

Comment: Do they have to be in the same order? Name1, Party1, Name2, Party2. Or can they be Name2, Party2, Name1, Party1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right your question, the following piece of code should help you:

```
f = open("file.csv")

parsed_lines = []
for line in f:
    vals = line.split(",")
    parsed_lines.append(map(str.strip, vals))

for idx, vals in enumerate(parsed_lines):
    for jdx in range(idx+1, len(parsed_lines)):
        if (vals[0]==parsed_lines[jdx][0]) and \
           (vals[1]==parsed_lines[jdx][1]) and \
           (vals[2]==parsed_lines[jdx][2]) and \
           (vals[3]==parsed_lines[jdx][3]):
            print "line #%s looks similar to line #%s" % (idx+1,jdx+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try built-in [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module and its `DictReader` class. Try something like this:

```
your_data = []
with open('data.csv') as csv_file:
     reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
     for row in reader:
         # check all of your conditions here
         if row['name1'] == 'S. Faber' and row['party1'] == 'CDA':
             your_data.append(row)
```

I did not test the code. But looks fine. You can find an example and more [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure about the data format, there's no need for object creation.

```
fo = open("data.csv", "r")
lines = fo.readlines()
"S. Faber, CDA, J.A. v. Kemenade, PvdA, 1980.06.24, http://polidocs.nl/XML/MOT/1970028.xml\n" in lines
```

notice the additional `\n` at the end of the string